# How do I include a css file while creating a wordpress theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header, stylesheet

I'm trying to create a wordpress theme.  After following some tutorials I've written this in my header.php

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');  ?> " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I have one CSS file, styles.css, in the same folder as the index.php.  What I have id weirdly calling CSS from somewhere, but not from the style.css file.  How do I make it call all its styles from the styles.css file??  Thanks : )

Comment: Have you tried using a barebones version of a theme thats empty except for the basic files that way you have everything you need instead of making the files by yourself, its much faster? And have you checked on wordpress.org for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a good idea to check the output of the `bloginfo('stylesheet_url');` function (say, by echoing it out somewhere) and see wether it actually points to your stylesheet. You can always use `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');` and add a filename to link to another file in the same dir.